# Netsuite Advanced PDF - Display Country Name instead of Country Code

Tags: netsuite

I have an Advanced PDF where I want to split the Billing Address into it's components, however when I use `${record.billcountry}` I get "AU" instead of "Australia".

What is the method to display the Country name instead of the ISO code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a horrible hack, based on the assumption that the country is always the last line of the address:

```
${record.billaddress?keep_after_last(">")}
```

It doesn't seem too easy to access the countries list to match the short names (the ISO code) to the full names from within the templates, but this works even if it looks horrid.  The `>` is of course just the last character of the html line break `<br />` which is in the address text, as passed to the template, between each line.

Comment: That's not a bad idea... Might give it a look later

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ${record.billcountry@text}?

Comment: Illegal built-in function: @text

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
- Failed at: ${record.billcountry@text} [in template "template" at line 45, column 75]

Comment: Can you try @label instead of @text?

Comment: Returns the word "Country"